# Iphone/Android GPS while app is not running

Tags: android, iphone, gps

Hey so I'm curious on application development for phones and whether its possible to create an app that tracks the users location, even when the app is not currently active on the phone.  (By active I mean the user has it opened). I did some initial investigation on iphone and it looked as if you could subscribe to "region changes" but not the actual location.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for iPhone this is one of the specific things you can do while your app is in the background state - see Apple docs "[iOS App Programming Guide: Apps States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)".

Comment: Thanks, It appears like one could create a app that when in the background sent gps data to a network server, that would then send APNS notifications events nearby.  I assume android has something similiar